# scrolling to element on page jquery - html,body refuses to scroll

Tags: jquery, html5boilerplate

I cannot understand this problem so I have to ask. I'm trying to do a very simple jQ scroll to element on a click event. I've successfully build the same function before on a different page.

```
$('li.newsmenu a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section#news').offset().top});
        return false;
});
```

My selectors are both fine.

I've tested the click event and it will give me an alert('like this');

In the console the **$('section#news').offset().top** value returns a sensible **717**.

I've tested in Chrome & Safari with no success.

I'm working on top of someone else's work and on top of the HTML5 boilerplate Wordpress theme system and I wonder if there is something in that.

Does anyone have any ideas? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Is there a site like jsfiddle, but just for dumping html, that I can use?

Comment: ok I think it all should be here: http://jsfiddle.net/BTyUY/ I had to block some stuff out [hope I got it all!] And there is no JS included, but my JS doesn't do much html/css alteration except for in specific areas. Jcarousel & Masonry

Comment: Your jQuery is fine. There must be a conflict somewhere...are you getting any errors. Simplified jsfiddle for your code is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/BTyUY/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/BTyUY/4/)

Comment: @SteveO - oh weird, this doesn't work for me in Chrome 16, but does in FF.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the jsfiddle. I took that code back and made it into an html page and it does something very weird with the div#top. Have a look with the .html file pasted here: http://pastebin.com/UfE8L8Vi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this looks like a webkit issue. By specifying

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

it is limiting their 'height' to that of the window. So `scrollTop(x)` never works. If you modify your CSS not to include these declarations everything works again. One other workaround would be to place your body content in a scrollable div and scroll THAT instead. I want to say that this is a webkit bug as the behavior seems bizarre. You can see it for yourself by scrolling down the window a little ways. Then query the current scrollTop value on everything, it's always zero! body, html, document, window, div#top, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the further insite. I wanted to debug it particularly as I believe that code came from the HTML5 Boilerplate wordpress theme and wasn't something added by my colleague. I think it is related to the sticky footer on that theme. I'm still new to StackOverflow but I think I should mark your answer correct as it solves the specific problem, even if it is almost a bug, is that the correct SO etiquette?

Comment: @iiz - this is kind of a gray area for this question. If you think a better solution is going to come along then I wouldn't accept my answer. If you think this is as good as it is going to get then accepting it is probably best. If down the road somebody discovers a better solution then it is perfectly to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok. Well I'm going to mark accepted as you found the root of problem I was having and therefor a solution to it, even the problem probably should have been happening in the first place. Thnx

Comment: you can add html, body { min-height: 100%; } instead of what you quoted